# series and sequences (arithmetic progression)

Tags: sequences-and-series

find sum of 14th and 17th term of an A.P whose total terms are 30 and sum of first and last term is 61.

Comment: So what is the formula that allows us to find the sum of an Arithmetic Series with given $n$ ?

Comment: Symmetry is your friend.

Comment: sum of arithmetic progression can be found by
S = n/2[2a + (n-1)d]
but in this question we don't know the first term and the difference..

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k=a_1+(k-1)d$. Than since $a_1+a_{30}=a_1+a_1+29d=2a_1+29d=61$, than $a_{14}+a_{17}=a_1+13d+a_1+16d=2a_1+29d=61$.